# EXT JS 5 : How to represent a java form to an ext js model?

Tags: java, javascript, rest, spring-mvc, extjs

I'm begginner in Ext JS and i want to send my Java Form to an ext js store who has a defined model : 
This is my Java Form :

```
public class Form {
    private member1;
    private member2;
    private List<AnotherType> membersList;

    //getters and setters
}
```

This is my store  :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Mystore', {

    extend   : 'Ext.data.Store',

    model : 'MyApp.model.MyModel',

    proxy : {
        type: 'rest',

        url : '/myapp/url/for/findForm',

        reader: {
            type: 'json'
            rootProperty : 'form'
        },

        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
}
```

How to define MyModel for include list of members ?

And how to use this list once my store is loaded ?
(it's a list to load a combox)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models could look something like this.  I've used a naming pattern similar to what you used in your question.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.model.Form", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "member1", type: "string"},
        {name: "member2", type: "string"},
    ],
    hasMany: {
        model: "MyApp.model.AnotherType",
        name: "membersList",
        associationKey: "membersList"
    }
});

Ext.define("MyApp.model.AnotherType", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "value", type: "string"},
        {name: "label", type: "string"},
    ]
});
```

You can create a combo box like this.

```
Ext.create("Ext.form.ComboBox", {
    fieldLabel: "Members",
    store: Ext.getStore("MyApp.store.Mystore").getAt(0).membersList(),
    queryMode: "local",
    displayField: "label",
    valueField: "value",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Note that the above is just an example using the first `MyApp.model.Form` in your store.  You'll likely want to create the combo box in a more generic way, but I'm not sure of the specifics for your case.

Comment: The combobox automatically take values in the membersList model ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the second part of your original question.  Do you want to show the list of members in a combo box?

Comment: Yes i want to populate my combobox with my membersList.